# Преимущества использования последних версий GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

В кроссплатформенной графической программе используется шейдеры написанные на GLSL версии 1.40.
Возможности GLSL 1.40 полностью удовлетворяют потребности приложения. Фактически используются базовые шейдеры для отрисовки текстуры:

Вершинный шейдер:

```
attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec2 textureCoordinates;

uniform mat3 transformationProjectionMatrix;

varying vec2 interpolatedTextureCoordinates;

void main() {
    interpolatedTextureCoordinates = textureCoordinates;
    gl_Position.xywz = vec4(transformationProjectionMatrix * vec3(position, 1.0), 0.0);
}
```

Фрагментный шейдер:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D textureData;

varying vec2 interpolatedTextureCoordinates;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor.rgba = color * texture(textureData, interpolatedTextureCoordinates).bgra;
}
```

Есть ли смысл иметь в программе несколько шейдеров под разные версии GLSL которые будут выбираться в зависимости от поддержки на конкретном оборудовании?
Возможно ли получить ускорение при использовании более современных версий языка шейдеров?

Comment: Можно, но явно не для таких тривиальных шейдеров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Возможно ли получить ускорение при использовании более современных версий языка шейдеров?

Нет, если не используются какие-либо функции для оптимизации, доступные в более свежих версиях, производительность на практике будет практически неизменной.

> Есть ли смысл иметь в программе несколько шейдеров под разные версии GLSL которые будут выбираться в зависимости от поддержки на конкретном оборудовании?

Как правило дублирование шейдеров для разных версий GLSL дополнительных преимуществ не дает (также не стоит смешивать разные версии GLSL в одной шейдерной программе). Поэтому имеет смысл использовать *наименьшую* версию GLSL, поддерживаемую вашим графическим движком, и применять более свежие версии только там где это необходимо.

Также дублирование шейдеров для разных версий GLSL не имеет большого смысла, так как один и тот же исходный код шейдера может быть скомпилирован для разных GLSL версий с помощью некоторых дополнительных ухищрений/макросов, поскольку GLSL сохраняет обратную совместимость (единственное большое изменение синтаксиса произошло в GLSL 150 / OpenGL 3.2, где также было выброшено много устаревшего функционала).

Тем не менее существуют ***баги** в драйверах OpenGL* которые могут изменить ситуацию. Например, на практике была ситуация, когда одна и та же GLSL программа не работала при компиляции как `#version 300 es` на устройстве поддерживающем OpenGL ES 3.0, и успешно работала при `#version 100 es`.

Также, можно ошибиться используя новые возможности GLSL официально не поддерживаемые в конкретной версии. Спецификация GLSL — вещь довольно сложная, можно потратить много времени в роли книжного червя, чтобы убедиться в какой версии добавлена та или иная функция. Помните, что многие драйверы допускают использование некоторых новых функций без указания соответствующей версии GLSL (если позволяет оборудование) и вы можете посчитать, что ваша программа GLSL соответствует к примеру `#version 140`, хотя на самом деле это не так, что может быть обнаружено при тестировании на другом драйвере OpenGL.

По моему опыту, драйверы NVIDIA **допускают значительные отклонения** от спецификации GLSL (вероятно потому, что NVIDIA компилятор GLSL переводит код на другой язык - [Cg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cg_(programming_language))). Драйверы AMD более строгие, но также допускают некоторые отклонения. Пока что из увиденных, самый строгий валидатор GLSL был в драйверах MacOS OpenGL. В таких условиях указание более высокой версии GLSL может быть более безопасным и надежным для совместимости с более широким спектром оборудования, хотя это просто скроет ошибки в определении самой низкой поддерживаемой версии GLSL.

[Перевод с SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65545736/should-i-use-the-last-glsl-version-where-it-is-possible/65548092#65548092)

Comment: Для проверки шейдеров также можно использовать [Khronos's glslang tool](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang)